# Form Recognizer Labeling Tool: Table detection Issue

Tags: ocr, labeling, azure-form-recognizer

As shown in this image 2, the labeling tool is detecting the table structure after running OCR, but it is not detecting the entire table. Instead, it is taking the first 2 columns only as shown in image 1.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image: picture 2]

Is there a way to make it capture all the 3 columns instead of 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is default table detection with OCR , you can have a table tag in azure form recognizer with labelling tool then train at least 5 similar invoices with table tag and labels , then use the trained model for prediction which will detect table correctly on a new invoice...

Here is the documentation which explains the complete steps

https://github.com/microsoft/knowledge-extraction-recipes-forms/blob/master/Scenarios/Table_Extraction_FR/README.md